# como cambiar el formato de fecha js

Tags: javascript

que tal estoy tratando de tomar una fecha de una variable que me esta tomando
la fecha con comas como el siguiente ejemplo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

necesito que me muestre la fecha con el formato 12/11/2021
esta seria mi variable

```
 let fechReg2 = $("#fecharegreso2").text();
```

y solo cambiarle el formato pero la esta tomando de una api entonces no puedo ajustarlo manualmente

error de la variable fecha
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Viene ese texto como valor de la fecha del API directamente?

Comment: Podrías usar simplemente toLocaleDateString y le puedes pasar el lenguaje con el que necesitas la fecha.

Comment: @H.Díaz  asi es de la api por eso no le pude modificar y 
gaidyjg  queria saber si se puede crear una variable con la cual me permita modificarle el formato y dejarle lo que necesito

Comment: prueba esto:
let date = new Date('16,Nov,2021').toLocaleDateString();

Comment: pero seria let date = new Date('dd/mm/aaaa').toLocaleDateString();

Comment: Sí, puedes cambiarle el formato según necesites, pero debes pasarlo como segundo parámetro al método toLocaleDateString en forma de objeto. Igual, si lo que necesitas es en formato dd/mm/yyyy con colocar es-ES en el primer parámetro debería bastarte

Comment: Con que al new Date() le pases como parámetro el string sería válido.

Comment: pues la ajuste con esta variable 
    let fechReg2 = $("#fecharegreso2").toLocaleDateString("dd/mm/yyyy"); y me marco error Uncaught TypeError: $(...).toLocaleDateString is not a function

Comment: Claro, porque lo que te viene en esa variable es un string, no un objeto Date. Debes convertir ese string en date y luego sí convertir ese valor con toLocaleDateString. Que como primer parámetro te toma el lenguaje (en-US, es-ES) y de segundo las opciones. Por eso te da error

Comment: asi:
 let fechReg2 = $("#fecharegreso2").text();
    let fechReg2 = $("#fecharegreso2").toLocaleDateString("dd/mm/yyyy");

Answer (score 5):

Puedes pasar tu fecha utilizando la clase `Date()` de JavaScript y pasando el método `toLocaleDateString` de la siguiente manera:

```js
let fecha = new Date("16,Nov,2021")
console.log(fecha.toLocaleDateString("en-US"));
```

Puedes leer la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) para informate de los diferentes tipos de formatos de fecha que hay.

Revisando nuevamente tu código me he dado cuenta que tienes algunos errores al momento de capturar tus inputs. para capturar valores con Jquery utilizas el método `val()`, te encuentras usando `text()` lo cual hace es poner un texto o string a un elemento del dom que lo permita

si quieres capturar tu fecha sería de la siguiente manera.

```
let fechReg2 = $("#fecharegreso2").val();
```

Esto debería retornarte una fecha en tu caso dice retornarte "16,Nov,2021" esté será el valor de tu variable fechReg2

luego con este valor sí podrías usar la clase `Date()` como lo explico al principo de mi respuesta, saludos.

Comment: que tal el formato de fecha me tomo un error cuando la ajuste a mi variable 
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).toLocaleDateString is not a function

Comment: ¿De que manera ajustaste la fecha a tu variable?

Comment: let fechReg2 = $("#fecharegreso2").toLocaleDateString("dd/mm/yyyy");

Comment: Lo que pasa es que el método `.toLocaleDateString` no existe en Jquery, lo que debes hacer es pasarle tu valor a `new Date()` y luego accedes al método `toLocaleDateString` de la siguiente manera `let fechReg2 = new Date($("#fecharegreso2").val()).toLocaleDateString()`

Comment: Además pasarle el formato de esta manera `toLocaleDateString("dd/mm/yyyy")` te retornará un error exactamente este `Uncaught RangeError: invalid language tag: "dd/mm/yyyy"`

Comment: asi es me manda el error 
Invalid Date 
por eso necesito que el formato de fecha que viene desde la api 16,Nov,2021
lo convierta a 16/11/2021

Comment: Acabo de editar mi respuesta, cuéntame si la solución nuevamente plantiada fue de tu ayuda

Comment: me manda vacio let fechReg2 = $("#fecharegreso2").val();
 ""}

Comment: Ahí está el problema, si te manda vacio puede ser varias cosas, tu #fecharegreso2 puede que esté mal escrito o ese input #fecharegreso2 no le has seleccionado un valor y por ende te retorna vacio